# sqlite3 / python 3.7 : executing a sql query is changing the value of a variable without me asking it to

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I wasn't quite sure how to word this, but let me just show you guys what I mean.

Here's all the python code I'm running (c is my cursor):

```
uResult = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users") 

pResult = c.execute("SELECT * FROM products")

for i in uResult:
    print(i[0])
    print(i[1])
```

The problem is, this is printing out data from the products table. Why??? This is driving me nuts...

Answer (score 1):

What is being returned by `c.execute()` is a [Cursor object](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor).
You want the resultset instead.
So do this:

```
uResult = c.execute("SELECT * FROM users").fetchall()

pResult = c.execute("SELECT * FROM products").fetchall()
```

Then things will work the way you expect.

Comment: Thank you! Don't understand what's happening exactly but this worked :)

Comment: You're welcome. With more exposure to the DB-API you'll get more familiar with how it operates. One reason for this separation of steps is that some SQL statements are meant to be executed without returning a resultset.